# I need to upload and rename an image onto my server

Tags: php

I'm very unskilled at php so I'm afraid I have no code to provide, but I don't think what I need is difficult to make anyway.

I need to create a form with two inputs, a "Name" field and a browse for file field, that will upload an image onto a folder in my server and rename that image to whatever was in the "name" field. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Look at the [manual for file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php), the [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function and [image](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) and [file system](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) related functions in general. Good luck!

Comment: Well it's not so much the uploading I need help with, but rather the "rename to the value in this field" I need help with. I can manage renaming to random variables and such, but I have no idea how to go about changing the name based on a form field.

Comment: Look at the `[$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)` variable. With that you can fetch the name of your extra field. And please post some code if you need more help. As you can see your question is downvoted and on the verge of being closed because of it's poor quality.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code

html file upload form

```html
<form name="fileUpload"  action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="40" required data-validation-required-message="Please select a name.">
  
  <input type="file" id="file" name="file_name" maxlength="40" required data-validation-required-message="Please select a photo.">
  
  <input type="submit" value="UPLOAD PHOTO"/>
  
  </form>
```

Now your upload.php file should look like this.

```html
<?php
$album_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$oldfileName = $_FILES["file_name"]["name"]; // The file name

move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "your upload file path" .$fileName);

$newfileName = "new name";

rename ( "your upload file path/" .$oldfileName$ , "your upload file path/" .$newfileName )
?>
```